# find by key in std::set

Tags: c++, stl, set, c++17

I struggle with a `std::set` that should support custom compare operations. My goal would be to be able to call find with just the key argument, without first creating an object of the set type. Something like this:

```
#include <set>
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>

class TestItem {
  public:
    std::uint64_t id;          // key
    std::vector<double> areas; // some other data
};

struct TestItemCompare {
    bool operator()(const std::uint64_t& lhs, const std::uint64_t& rhs) {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
    bool operator()(const std::uint64_t& lhs, const TestItem& rhs) {
        return lhs < rhs.id;
    }
    bool operator()(const TestItem& lhs, const std::uint64_t& rhs) {
        return lhs.id < rhs;
    }
    bool operator()(const TestItem& lhs, const TestItem& rhs) {
        return lhs.id < rhs.id;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::set<TestItem, TestItemCompare> store;
    std::uint64_t id = 0;
    TestItem t;
    t.id = 0;

    auto it1 = store.find(t);    // compiles
    auto it2 = store.find(id);   // fails to compile

    return 0;
}
```

I thought this was possible...

Comment: are you sure you dont want to use a `std::map` instead?

Comment: No the support for what you ask for is being added only in C++20. Still why not simply use `std::map<int,std::vector<double>>`? As suggested in the comment above.

Comment: @ALX23z transparent compares are in C++14, are you thinking of transparent hashes for unordered containers?

Comment: Good point about std::map. What is the advantage of set, really? I thought it might be efficient since it does not duplicate the key (I need the key in the data structure as well). But in this case the key is not that large.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is possible. But your comparator must be a transparent one. And the member functions in functor need to be const

```cpp
struct TestItemCompare {
    using is_transparent = int; // actually any alias will do, void, custom type
    bool operator()(const std::uint64_t& lhs, const std::uint64_t& rhs) const {
        return lhs < rhs;
    }
    bool operator()(const std::uint64_t& lhs, const TestItem& rhs) const {
        return lhs < rhs.id;
    }
    bool operator()(const TestItem& lhs, const std::uint64_t& rhs) const {
        return lhs.id < rhs;
    }
    bool operator()(const TestItem& lhs, const TestItem& rhs) const {
        return lhs.id < rhs.id;
    }
};
```

Comment: This works! I have nevertheless used a map because I needed to be able to modify the item found (not the key, but other content). This can be done with a map but not with a set.